# What percentage of asylum seekers who entered the EU during the 2015 refugee crisis are no longer receiving welfare?

Tags: european-union, refugees, social-welfare

At the height of the 2015 refugee crisis in Europe there have been numerous arguments over the economic utility of arriving asylum seekers. On one hand of the spectrum, representatives of the left wing were claiming that most of the refugees are skilled workers and [would be quickly absorbed into the economy](https://archive.is/2qtli). Meanwhile representatives of the right wing were claiming that the incoming immigrants are going to be forever dependent on welfare and would never find a proper job.

Now that it's been more than 6 years since the peak of the crisis and the refugees have had a reasonable amount of time to settle into their new home, do we have any statistics on the number of asylum seekers who are no longer receiving welfare? As a corollary, are there statistics on the number of refugees who are gainfully employed?

> NB: question has been updated for the 2023 bounty. I'm looking for the most recent available statistics.

Comment: Most of the asylum requests in Germany were actually filed in 2016 https://www.thelocal.de/20171215/six-common-questions-people-have-about-refugees-in-germany

Comment: Note that in most countries, while the asylum application is in progress, you are *not allowed to work*.

Comment: Regarding the bounty, if you want an "up to date" answer you should consider clarifying whether you want statistics showing the situation in 2023 or updated statistics concerning the situation in 2019.  The question currently implies the latter.

Comment: "claiming that most of the refugees are skilled workers and would be quickly absorbed into the economy." <- citation needed. The left wing argument is generally based on humanitarian reasons and the existence of a fundamental right to asylum (especially in Europe, for historical reasons), not usability by the economy.

Comment: @tim fair point, citation added

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm not doubting that some people are making the argument, but it's inherently a right-wing/neo-liberal argument, not a left-wing one. The article cites the conservative Angela Merkel and industrial leaders as making the argument; hardly proponents of left-wing policies.

Comment: @tim please ask a separate question if you'd like to debate what each side was saying during the 2015-2016 immigration crisis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Germany, refugees are [by default](https://www.bmas.de/DE/Arbeit/Fachkraeftesicherung-und-Integration/Migration-und-Arbeit/Flucht-und-Aysl/arbeitsmarktzugang-fuer-fluechtlinge.html) not allowed to work. They need a permit, which they can only get after 3-9 months (if at at; refugees in a "Aufnahmeeinrichtung", refugees from a list of specific countries, and those that are "Geduldet" cannot apply at all). So a higher than average unemployment rate is to be expected.

Germany still doesn't collect job figures only for refugees. But for the 8 countries of origin for refugees (the statistic mentioned in [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/40597/8062)), [employment has risen](https://mediendienst-integration.de/integration/arbeitsmarkt.html) (light blue is fully employed, dark blue is part time, yellow is without work):

[image]

As of Mai 2022, 227430 are unemployed, 74800 are partially employed, and 483800 are fully employed (that's an unemployment rate of 28.9% compared to 45% back then).

For comparison, for foreigners in Germany, the rate is [7.6%](https://mediendienst-integration.de/integration/arbeitsmarkt.html), for people with a migration background 6.2%, for native Germans without migration background it's 2.6%.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like the right wing parties were entirely correct in their predictions

Comment: @JonathanReez How so? The unemployment numbers are steadily declining and a base rate of unemployment can be explained by the fact that some aren't allowed to work. Don't use my answer to justify xenophobia.

Comment: 28.9% unemployment is ~10 times higher than the unemployment rate of native Germans. It's not about xenophobia, it's about the importance of having a points-based immigration system and being able to deport anyone who fails to find a job.

Comment: @JonathanReez This isn't about immigrants at all; it's about refugees. These are  different topics. In either case, the numbers don't show that "the incoming immigrants are going to be forever dependent on welfare and would never find a proper job", it shows that a majority of refugees have found a "proper" job and that there's a steady upwards trend in employment.

Comment: Yes, it's about illegal immigrants, not regular legal immigrants. The problem is that once you allow them into the country there's currently no easy path for sending them back if they fail to fully assimilate after X years.

Comment: @JonathanReez It's about refugees, not illegal immigrants. The right to asylum is enshrined in national and international law. But I don't feel like this is going anywhere, as there seems to be a fundamental disagreement on basic human rights.

Comment: The vast majority of refugees in Germany have crossed via at least 1 safe country on their way to German territory and are thus not genuine refugees. The only exception would be people who flew in directly to Germany from Syria. There's been many cases where Syrian refugees were granted asylum in eastern parts of the EU but then chose to illegally cross the border and apply for asylum in Germany.

Comment: @JonathanReez Do I understand correctly that you equate "fully assimilate" with "having a job"? Is that true for children as well? And what about refugees promoting traditional values such as a family structure with a husband providing for the family, and the wife taking care of the household?

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump. fully assimilate = speak German (or whatever is the local language) at C1 level and not receive any welfare from the government.

Comment: @tim Thanks for providing concrete data and sources, and emphasizing the fact that many refugees are not allowed to work. I feel this answer could be improved by an indication of what percentage of immigrants is allowed to work.

Comment: @JonathanReez Keep in mind  that many Germans that have a job still depend on state welfare, and many Germans that do not have a job do not depend on state welfare. The same is true for refugees in Germany. You seem very eager to jump to very specific conclusions on some rather thin and weakly specified data.

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump. If you have stats on what % of refugees are receiving welfare (in any EU country), that could be a great answer. So far all we have is indirect data.

Comment: Are people who are not permitted to work included in the statistics?  Unemployment statistics normally include only those who are looking for work, which people who are not permitted to work are also not permitted to do.

Comment: @phoog I couldn't find any info on that, but in either case I don't feel like giving right-wing xenophobia any more fuel here. Because in the end, the numbers don't matter. Some people just don't like or want foreigners here. It doesn't matter if they are asylum seekers (who are accepted temporarily for protection and deported after 3 years if they don't have a job or c1-level German skills) or permanent migrants (for whom the barrier to entry is high), it doesn't matter if they have a job or not. It's all the same, and none of them are welcome.

Comment: You’d be very surprised to learn that I’m personally an immigrant to the EU. But it’s all the same - any negative opinion about the so-called refugees is tantamount to xenophobia because that’s how politics works.

Comment: @tim how is someone who has been granted asylum deported after three years if they fail to learn German or get a job?  How does Germany justify this under the refugee convention?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose this a partial answer, for lack of something better... [TheLocal.de said in Dec 2017](https://www.thelocal.de/20171215/six-common-questions-people-have-about-refugees-in-germany) (using a proxy measure) that unemployment among refugees was 45%:

> Research by the OECD suggests that refugees in Europe tend to lag behind the native populations in terms of employment. A 2014 report found that refugee employment rates are around 20 percent lower than those for native populations with similar educational backgrounds.
>
> Germany does not collect job figures on refugees. But statistics for citizens of the eight most significant countries of origin for refugees give approximate data. This shows employment levels much lower than among the general population. Whereas just five percent of Germans were unemployed in September, 45 percent of people from these eight countries were not in employment.
>
> The Federal Job Agency notes that "poor language skills and a lack of formal training make it difficult for refugees to integrate into the job market", warning that "a deep breath is needed" in overcoming these problems.
>
> The good news is that the proportion of refugees who are registered as unemployed dropped by 7.4 percent in a year (although most of these people have gone into further education courses rather than employment).
>
> German employers who have hired refugees have been pleased with the work they have done. An OECD survey carried out earlier this year with over 2,000 employers found that around 80 percent were satisfied with the work done by refugees in their employment.

It also notes that in order to obtain permanent residence they would have to get off welfare (and show proficiency in German). Presumably that's the carrot.

Comment: Given the prevalence of [mini jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_employment) in Germany, simply being employed does not equal to being off welfare, unfortunately.

Comment: @JonathanReez another thing to consider would be the number of asylum seekers who are no longer in Germany.

Comment: @phoog yep, that's fair. Ideally it would be good to have some recent statistics on what % of refugees are still in the country and still receiving government payments of any kind.

Comment: @JonathanReez I just found an article saying 500,000 refugees entered in 2015 and 750,000 in 2016, while UNHCR says that there were 1.24 million present in Germany in 2021.  So clearly a significant proportion of the 1.25 million who entered in 2015 and 2016 are gone (or perhaps are present but no longer counted in refugee statistics, for example if they obtained some other status).